# Button onclick not redirecting to correct URL

Tags: javascript

`<button id="promoCodeSubmit" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.test.com'+document.getElementById('promoCodeValue').value;">Apply</button>`

Trying to use the code above to redirect a page. console.log is printing out the correct URL, but page gets redirected incorrectly. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi Megan. Page gets redirected incorrectly where? Can you share more of your code so we can see what console.log is picking up, and what is ending up in the redirect?

Comment: What is console.log printing and where are you actually getting redirected to?

Comment: Brett, Sorry, I can only give so much info because its related to an event registration and my boss is paranoid...but it's redirecting to a 404 on the same domain. However, I can go directly to test.com/promoCodeValue and that works.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/huNx9/)

The following works fine for me, let me know if you need more.

**HTML**

```
<button id="promoCodeSubmit" onclick="ClickEvent()">Apply</button>
<input type="hidden" id="promoCodeValue" value="1"/>
```

**JS**

```
function ClickEvent(){
    window.location.href='http://www.test.com'+document.getElementById('promoCodeValue').value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't simplify your code and make it readable.It will also solve your problem.
HTML

```
<button id="promoCodeSubmit" onclick="RedirectToLocation()">Apply</button>

<input id="promoCodeValue" type="text" value="testing123" />
```

Script:

```
function RedirectToLocation(){
 window.location.href='http://www.test.com'+document.getElementById('promoCodeValue').value;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXXWz/1/)